# Run gtest util it fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio, testing, googletest

Is there a way to run the google test in Visual Studio until it fails??

I have this `TEST_F(PersistentStorageTestFixture, test_PSF_U13)` test fails but it is intermittent. I need to run it again and again until it fails, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can place options after google test command.
To run only some unit tests you could use --gtest_filter=Test_name* command line option with a value which is a regular expression.

Then you can create a script to run the program in a loop until it returns something different than 0.

```
// Use this macro in main() to run all tests.  It returns 0 if all
// tests are successful, or 1 otherwise.
//
// RUN_ALL_TESTS() should be invoked after the command line has been
// parsed by InitGoogleTest().

#define RUN_ALL_TESTS()\
  (::testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->Run())
```